# question regarding switch conditionals in php

Tags: php, comparison, switch-statement

I was hoping someone had a clue as to why I got the following outputs because I was expecting something else.

```
$x = NULL;
switch ($x) {
    case "0": 
        echo "String"; 
        break;
    case 0: 
        echo "Integer"; 
        break;
    case NULL: 
        echo "NULL"; 
        break;
    case FALSE: 
        echo "Boolean"; 
        break;
    case "": 
        echo "Empty string"; 
        break;
    default: 
        echo "Something else"; 
        break;
}
// outputs "Integer" was expecting "NULL"

$x=6;
switch ($x) {
    case "6b": 
        echo "6b"; 
        break;
    case "6": 
        echo "6 empty"; 
        break;
    case 6: 
        echo "6 full"; 
        break;
    default: 
        echo "6 half";
        break;
}
// outputs "6b" was expecting "6 empty"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual [says](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> Note that switch/case does loose comparision.

It will first check whether `NULL == "0"` which is false as `NULL` as a string is not `"0"`.

`NULL` as integer is `0` so that will match - printing Integer.

For the `6`, it will convert the cases to integers - `"6b"` will become `6` which is equal.

So it's because:

```
NULL != "0";
NULL == 0;

"6b" == 6;
```

Answer (score 2):

Note:

Note that switch/case does loose comparision.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

So in stead of doing a comparison like: `$x === 0`  you do `$x == 0`

Answer (score 2):

The comparison done by switch/case works with type jugling.

Basically, it uses the `==` operator, and not the `===` one.

Quoting [Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) :

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically. 
> These rules also apply to the switch
>   statement.

Comment: Whilst you're right, I think you quoted the wrong paragraph. The comparison in question doesn't involve strings at all.

Comment: At least in the second example ofthe OP, there are strings, integers, and numerical strings *(not so much for the first one)*

Comment: Oh, OK, there's a second one. Wow, what an inconcise question >.<

Answer (score 1):

$x is automatically converted to an integer when doing the comparison "$x = 0". You might want to use an `if/else if` structure instead, and use `$x === 0` to do the comparison. `===` means "strictly equal to".